# Xamarin, Android: How to use AdListener?

Tags: android, xamarin

Im showing an interstitial ad in my app:

```
   if (mInterstitialAd.IsLoaded == true)
   {
       mInterstitialAd.Show();
   }
   else
   {
       Log.Info("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
   }
```

This does work SOMETIMES. But most of the times, the add hasn't finished loading, so we'll end up in the else part.

Now, I read about AdListener, that display the add as soon as they know it has loaded. I just couldn't find an example in C# of how to do that. The one for JAVA that I found I coudln't get to work right.

Just a little help would be awesome :)

THANKS!

Comment: no one any idea? :(

Comment: I answered your another question, I think it's the same question as this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin, Android: Using the AdListener right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229061/xamarin-android-using-the-adlistener-right)