# Xamarin, Android: Using the AdListener right

Tags: android, xamarin, ads

I'm trying to use the AdListener in C#. 
I have an interstitial ad loading when the app is first started, but sometimes my ad gets skipped because it isn't fully loaded yet. I think an Adlistener should do the trick.

Unfortunately, I have NO CLUE on how to implement it. Also, there is no tutorial on how to do it in C# only in Java and I couldn't find a translation for it :(

Add:

```
    adListener.OnAdLoaded() += (o, e) =>
    {
        mInterstitialAd.Show();
    };
```

This doesn't work :(

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class which inherits from `Android.Gms.Ads.AdListener`, then use the instance of this class as the Listener for your `mInterstitialAd`, for example:

```
mInterstitialAd.AdListener = new AdListener(this);
```

`AdListener`:

```
private class AdListener : Android.Gms.Ads.AdListener
{
    private MainActivity that;

    public AdListener(MainActivity t)
    {
        that = t;
    }

    public override void OnAdLoaded()
    {
        base.OnAdLoaded();
    }

    public override void OnAdClosed()
    {
        that.RequestNewInterstitial();
        that.BeginSecondActivity();
    }
}
```

You can also checked the official demo for xamarin android ad: [AdMobExample Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/AdMobExample/).